# Best way to check if a list is empty in java

Tags: java, arraylist

which should we prefer
sample code :

```
 List list = new ArrayList();
    list.size()==0 or list.isEmpty()
```

with performance perspective.

Comment: So, you've profiled your code and you've found that this method call is a true bottle-neck in your code's performance? If not, this sounds like spinning wheels and premature optimization.

Comment: no.it was not like that. it was just for better understanding.and thanx whoever provided me the link for the answer.

Comment: @abhinaba yes i know that i know nothing but i know how to take a look over java api. it's k..thanx .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an `ArrayList`

Frankly, it won't make much of a difference. Why?. `isEmpty()` does this :

```
 public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
```

Also, I think the JIT might inline this code so `isEmpty()` might not take more time.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to tune performance on such a low level. It will not have any noticeale impact and might even result in the same bytecode depending on the compiler. Choose the more readable, self-expressive approach instead, which in this case is `isEmpty`, as it says exactly what it does.

Comment: I don't think that we could ever get the *same* byte code. I mean the methods are part of the `List` interface. They are overridden.. The compiler just can't *place* the method there